# Determinant and inverse matrix calculation of a special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Is there any smart way of calculating the determinant of this kind matrix?

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots &  n \\
2 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n-1 \\ 
3 & 2 & 1 & \cdots & n-2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
n & n-1 & n-2 & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix}

I encountered this in a problem for the case $n=4$. I need to find the inverse matrix.
I doubt the idea of this problem is to calculate all the cofactors and then the inverse matrix in the usual way.
I see the pattern here and some recursive relations... but I am not sure if this helps for calculating the determinant of the existing matrix.

Comment: Would you kindly make sure that I did not mess up your matrix in the editing?

Comment: I take it that by "reverse" matrix, you mean "inverse" matrix. But it's not clear whether you are asking for the determinant, or for the inverse.

Comment: @AndrewChin It's correct. Thank you.

Comment: I am asking for the inverse matrix which involves calculating the determinant of the existing matrix.

Comment: What makes you think finding the inverse of a matrix necessarily involves calculating the determinant?

Comment: It's the only way I know, I think.

Comment: Isn't the matrix a symmetric Toeplitz matrix? You don't need the determinant in general. There are matrix decompositions you can use.

Comment: The usual way to find $A^{-1}$ is to set up the augmented matrix $(A|I)$ and then row reduce to the form $(I|B)$. When you do that, $B=A^{-1}$. No determinants involved.

Comment: The row reduction goes fairly smoothly, if for each $j$ you add row $j+2$ to row $j$, and then subtract twice row $j+1$.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who commented or provided an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If it’s the determinant you are looking for, then what if you subtract column $j+1$ from column $j$ to get the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 & -1& \cdots &  n \\
1& -1 & -1& \cdots & n-1 \\ 
1& 1& -1 & \cdots & n-2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1& 1& 1& \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix}_{n\times n}$$

Then you could add the bottom row to the top row to get $[0,0,...,n+1]$ then the determinant will be
$$(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)\begin{vmatrix}
1& -1 & -1& \cdots & -1\\ 
1& 1& -1 & \cdots & -1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1& 1& 1& \cdots & 1 \end{vmatrix}_{(n-1)\times(n-1)}$$

From which you can always add the bottom row to the top to get $[2,0,...,0]$, so you end up getting

$(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)2^{n-2}$?

It looks like for the $n \times n$ matrix $A$ given, the inverse has the general form

$$B=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{-n}{2(n+1)}& \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & \frac{1}{2(n+1)} \\
\frac{1}{2} & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \cdots & 0& 0 \\ 
0 & \frac{1}{2} & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & \cdots & 0&0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -1 & \cdots & 0&0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &-1&\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2(n+1)} & 0 & 0 & 0& \cdots &\frac{1}{2}& \frac{-n}{2(n+1)} \end{pmatrix}
$$

I don't really have proof of how I got this except plugging in the matrix to an inverse matrix calculator for various values of $n$ and noticing a pattern. But one can certainly check that it is indeed the inverse, multiplying on the left and getting $B\cdot A=I$ ensures it is the inverse.

To check this, when multiplying this matrix on the left, it’s not hard to check for the rows of the form $[0,...,\frac{1}{2},-1,\frac{1}{2},...,0]$ because either we have three consecutive integers $n,n+1,n+2$ or $n,n-1,n-2$ $$\frac{n}{2}-(n+1)+\frac{n+2}{2}=0$$ $$\frac{n}{2}-(n-1)+\frac{n-2}{2}=0$$ or $$2\cdot\frac{1}{2}+(-1)\cdot 1+ 2\cdot \frac{1}{2}=1$$ which always is a diagonal entry. Then considering the top row:

$$\frac{-n}{2(n+1)} + 2\cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{n}{2(n+1)}=1$$

$$(i+1)\cdot\frac{-n}{2(n+1)}+ i\cdot \frac{1}{2} + (n-i)\cdot  \frac{1}{2(n+1)}=0$$ for $i=1,2,...,n-1$.

The bottom row acts similarly. Thus we indeed get $I$. This probably yields to a nice method to find the inverse through $[A|I] \rightsquigarrow [I|B]$.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots &  n \\
2 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n-1 \\ 
3 & 2 & 1 & \cdots & n-2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
n & n-1 & n-2 & \cdots & 1 \end{vmatrix}$$
Notice the sum of an element from the first column and an element from the last column (with the same row) will always be equal to $n+1$,thus we can do $(C_1 = C_1+C_n)$
$$ = \begin{vmatrix}
n+1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots &  n \\
n+1 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n-1 \\ 
n+1 & 2 & 1 & \cdots & n-2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
n+1 & n-1 & n-2 & \cdots & 1 \end{vmatrix} = (n+1)
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots &  n \\
1 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n-1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 & \cdots & n-2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & n-1 & n-2 & \cdots & 1 \end{vmatrix}$$
From here, we can do as follows: 
go from the last row towards the first and decrease each row's value with the one above it (for any row but the first one).
($\forall i \neq 1, R_i=R_i-R_{i-1}$, Starting with $i=n$ then $i=n-1 ... i=2$).
$$ = (n+1)\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots &  n \\
0 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 \\ 
0 & 1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & -1 \end{vmatrix}$$
Expand $C_1$:
$$ = (n+1)\begin{vmatrix}
-1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots &  -1 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 \\ 
1 & 1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & -1 \end{vmatrix}$$
Now Add the first row to all of the other rows ($\forall i \neq 1, R_i = R_i + R_1$).
$$ = (n+1)\begin{vmatrix}
-1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots &  -1 \\
0 & -2 & -2 & \cdots & -2 \\ 
0 & 0 & -2 & \cdots & -2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -2 \end{vmatrix} = (n+1)[-(-2)^{n-2}]$$

Comment: +1: Nice! Getting it to be upper triangular making the determinant obvious :D

Answer (score 2):

Treat $n$ as a parameter, let

- $M$ be your $n \times n$ matrix.
- $\eta$ be the $n\times n$ matrix with $1$ on the lower diagonal and $0$ otherwise.
- $\bar{\eta}$ be the transpose of $\eta$.
- $u$ be the $n \times 1$ column vector with all entries $1$.
- $e$ be the $n \times 1$ column vector with $1$ on first row and $0$
  otherwise.
- $f$ be the $n \times 1$ column vector with $1$ on last row and $0$

There are several algebraic facts we need.

1. $\eta$ and $\bar{\eta}$ are nil-potent. More precisley, $\eta^n = \bar{\eta}^n = 0$.
2. $\eta\bar{\eta} = I - ee^T$ and $\bar{\eta}\eta = I -ff^T$.
3. $uu^T = (I-\eta)^{-1} + \bar{\eta}(I-\bar{\eta})^{-1} = (I-\eta)^{-1}\eta + (I-\bar{\eta})^{-1}$.
4. $(I - \eta)u  = e$, $(1 - \bar{\eta}) u = f$ and $(I - \bar{\eta}) e = e$.

If one look at the lower triangular part of $M$, it equals to
$$I + 2\eta + 3\eta^2 + \cdots + n\eta^{n-1} = (I - \eta)^{-2}$$
Similar things happens to the upper triangular part of $M$. This leads to:

$$
\begin{align}M 
&= (I - \eta)^{-2} + (I-\bar{\eta})^{-2} - I\\
&= (I-\eta)^{-1}(uu^T - \bar{\eta}(1-\bar{\eta})^{-1})
 + (uu^T - (1-\eta)^{-1}\eta)(1 - \bar{\eta})^{-1} - I\\
&= (I-\eta)^{-1}((ue^T - \bar{\eta})  + (eu^T - \eta))(1-\bar{\eta})^{-1} - I
\end{align}
$$
As a result, following product of matrix has a relatively simple structure:

$$\begin{align}
N \stackrel{def}{=} (1-\eta)M(1-\bar{\eta}) 
&= (eu^T - \eta) + (ue^T - \bar{\eta}) - (I - \eta)(I - \bar{\eta})\\
&= ee^T + eu^T + ue^T - 2I
\end{align}$$

Let $v = \frac{u - e}{\sqrt{n-1}}$. It is easy $e, v$ are orthogonal unit vectors. Extend $\{ e, v \}$ to an orthonormal basis. In the new basis, $N$ is block-diagonalized and has the form
$$N_{new} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \sqrt{n-1} & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
\sqrt{n-1} & -2 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0  & -2 & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & -2
\end{bmatrix}$$
Since $\det(1-\eta) = \det(1-\bar{\eta}) = 1$, we find

$$\det(M) = \det(N) = (-2-(n-1))(-2)^{n-2} = -(n+1)(-2)^{n-2}$$

In the new basis, inverting $N$ comes down to inverting a $2 \times 2$ matrix. In terms of $e, v$, we have

$$\begin{align}
N^{-1} &= \frac{1}{n+1}(2 ee^T + \sqrt{n-1}(ve^T + ev^T) - vv^T) - \frac12(I - ee^T - vv^T)\\
&= \frac{ue^T + eu^T}{n+1}
+ (\frac12-\frac{1}{n+1})vv^T - \frac12(I- ee^T)\\
&= \frac{ue^T + eu^T}{n+1} + \frac{(u-e)(u-e)^T}{2(n+1)}
 - \frac12(I - ee^T)\\
&= \frac{(u+e)(u+e^T)}{2(n+1)} - \frac12(I- ee^T)
\end{align}
$$
This leads to
$$\begin{align}M^{-1} 
&= (1-\bar{\eta})N^{-1}(1-\eta)\\
&= \frac{(e+f)(e+f)^T}{2(n+1)} - \frac12((I-\bar{\eta})(I-\eta)-ee^T)\\
&= \frac{(e+f)(e+f)^T}{2(n+1)} - \frac12(I - \eta - \bar{\eta} + \bar{\eta}\eta - ee^T)\\
&= \underbrace{-I + \frac12(\eta + \bar{\eta})}_J + \underbrace{\frac{(n+2)(ee^T+ff^T) + (ef^T+fe^T)}{2(n+1)}}_K
\end{align}
$$
This implies $M^{-1}$ is very close to a tri-diagonal matrix

$$J = -I + \frac12(\eta + \bar{\eta})
\quad\text{ with }\quad J_{ij} = \begin{cases}
-1, & i = j\\
\frac12, & |i - j| = 1\\
0, & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

The difference $K$ is non-zero only at following $4$ entries:

$$K_{11} = K_{nn} = \frac{n+2}{2(n+1)},\quad K_{n1} = K_{1n} = \frac{1}{2(n+1)}$$

As an example, following is what $M^{-1}$ looks like at $n = 7$.
$$\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{7}{16} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{16}\cr \frac{1}{2} & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -1 & \frac{1}{2}\cr \frac{1}{16} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{7}{16}\end{bmatrix}$$

One can see that
$M^{-1}_{17} = M^{-1}_{71} = \frac{1}{2(7+1)} = \frac{1}{16}$ and
$M^{-1}_{11} = M^{-1}_{77} = \frac{7+2}{2(7+1)} - 1 = -\frac{7}{16}$. Matching what we have computed before.

Answer (score 2):

Call your matrix $A$. Let $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_{n-1}\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^{n-1}$. Let also $e=\sum_ie_i=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$ and
$$
L=\pmatrix{1\\ -1&1\\ &\ddots&\ddots\\ &&-1&1}.
$$
Then $B:=LAL^T=\pmatrix{1&e^T\\ e&-2I_{n-1}}$. Using [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), we obtain
$$
\det(A)=\det(B)=\det(-2I_{n-1})\left(1-e^T(-2I_{n-1})^{-1}e\right)=(-2)^{n-1}\frac{n+1}{2}.
$$
To find $A^{-1}$, partition $L$ as $\pmatrix{1&0\\ -e_1&L'}$. Then
\begin{aligned}
A^{-1}
&=L^TB^{-1}L\\
&=\pmatrix{1&-e_1^T\\ 0&L'^T}
\pmatrix{\frac{2}{n+1}&\frac{1}{n+1}e^T\\ \frac{1}{n+1}e&\frac{1}{2(n+1)}ee^T-\frac12I_{n-1}}
\pmatrix{1&0\\ -e_1&L'}\\
&=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{n+1}&\frac{1}{2(n+1)}e^T+\frac12e_1^T\\ \ast&\frac{1}{2(n+1)}e_ne^T-\frac12L'^T}
\pmatrix{1&0\\ -e_1&L'}\\
&=\pmatrix{\frac{-n}{2(n+1)}&\frac{1}{2(n+1)}e_n^T+\frac12e_1^T\\ \ast&\frac{1}{2(n+1)}e_ne_n^T-\frac12L'^TL'}.
\end{aligned}
By direct calculation, $L'^TL'$ is the symmetric tridiagonal matrix whose main diagonal is $(2,\ldots,2,1)$ and whose superdiagonal is a vector of $-1$s. Since $A^{-1}$ is symmetric, we finally get
$$
A^{-1}=\pmatrix{
\frac{-n}{2(n+1)}&\frac12&&&\frac{1}{2(n+1)}\\
\frac12&-1&\frac12\\
&\frac12&-1&\ddots\\
&&\ddots&\ddots&\frac12\\
\frac{1}{2(n+1)}&&&\frac12&\frac{-n}{2(n+1)}
}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, the inverse of the closely related matrix $(a_{ij}) = (\frac{n}{4}- \frac{1}{2} |i-j|)$ is still Toeplitz and symmetric with first row $(2,-1, 0, \ldots, 0, 1)$, determinant $4$, and eigenvalues coming in pairs ( and a $4$, when $n$ odd). Moreover, one can explicitely find the eigenvectors of this inverse, using trigonometric functions. Now, there is a formula for the inverse of a peturbation of a matrix by a matrix of rank $1$. So finding the inverse is feasible.

As an example, check out this inverse ( case $n=5$): [WA link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Inverse%5B%20Table%5B%205%2F4%20-%201%2F2%20%20Abs%5Bi-j%5D%2C%20%7Bi%2C1%2C5%7D%2C%7Bj%2C1%2C5%7D%5D%5D) .